# How to use passphrase for RSA Private Key in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, openssl

I want to encrypt and decrypt information in flutter using a private key which contains a passphrase and a public key. But I can't find any package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) allowing to read the private key by filling in the passphrase. I would like to ask for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this package:

pub.dev/packages/rsa_encrypt